# Microsoft reportviewer cant use in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, winforms, nuget-package

[image]

Microsoft reportviewer cant use in WPF

Comment: Your dot net version? Because there is no report viewer for dot net 5 and on-wards.

Comment: Report Viewer will only work if your using dot net 4.8

Comment: I think it is version 4

Comment: install this nuget in your project https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms/

Comment: And there is a WindowsFormsHost control in wpf, you can use that control to put Windows form report viewer in wpf

Comment: here is an example https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/nipuntomar/report-viewer-control-in-wpf/

Comment: `ReportViewer` is a *WinForms* component, not a WPF component. You must add it in the `.NET Framework Components` tab if it's not there already. Adding a WinForms component on a WPF page is described in the WPF docs, at [Walkthrough: Hosting a Windows Forms Control in WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-hosting-a-windows-forms-control-in-wpf?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just add Reportviewer control into toolbox to drag and drop, you must require to use `WindowsFormsHost` to put reportviewer control into your application

Something like below :
WindowsFormsHost wHost = new WindowsFormsHost();
var reportV = new ReportViewer();
wHost.Child = reportV;